# ACTION_SHUTDOWN not getting called from Broadcast Receiver on android Q (10) and higher

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I have the following Broadcast Receiver

```
 class ShutdownReceiver(): BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN == intent?.action) {
            HiddenFileUtility.appendLogs("ACTION_SHUTDOWN: true")
            ApplicationGlobalContext.setShutDownState(true)
        }
    }

}
```

I register the `ShutdownReceiver` through the `AndroidManifext.xml` like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceivers.ShutdownReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" android:priority="999"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And i never receive the `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Android` official documentation states that `As of Build.VERSION_CODES#P this broadcast is only sent to receivers registered through Context.registerReceiver` [link here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SHUTDOWN)

The solution is to delete the `ShutdownReceiver` from the `AndroidManifest.xml` and register it using `Context.registerReceiver` like this:

```
val shutdownReceiver = ShutdownReceiver();
val bootIntentFilter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN);
context.registerReceiver(shutdownReceiver, bootIntentFilter);
```

Comment: can you give a proper example for action_shutdown reciever, because in my case it is not working on background , means when we clearing from recent apps list, it is not working , i used foreground services, but no use , still i doesn't work on background

Comment: @Nj_ninteyFIve did you delete the receiver declaration from AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @no actually i didn't add a receiver in manifest file , because i have used this receiver inside my foreground service class , here i am sharing the link of my code

Comment: Gabriel Rujoiuhere  the code link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72461942/broadcast-reciever-action-shutdown-intent-is-not-working-in-android-version-11)

Comment: when you google here it shows the first link of my code "broadcast-reciever-action-shutdown-intent-is-not-working-in-android-version-11"

Comment: @Nj_ninteyFIve From what i have seen in your question, your problem is related with a SMS Receiver. Me personally i also had issues with SMS receivers on Android 11 and above. Try to test your code on lower android versions to isolate the problem. It might be the android version that's causing the problem

Comment: no that's not the issue, when i trying to check the log it doesn't call onReceive method , when i switch off the device, that means shutdown receiver is not working while the app is on background.